# Deploy the Gulp Build Folder To Azure from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release-management, azure-pipelines

I just started using VSO for one of my project. I have created the built definition and the built was successful. When I tried to create the release definition for that built its failing by throwing the error

```
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: No files were found to deploy with search pattern C:\a\858bddd5b\**\*.zip
```

Its expecting .zip files. Since I need to deploy the distributed folder created by gulp build, I have given the Web Deploy Package path as

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/{built name}
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a build step to create an archive with .zip extension for the output folder of the gulp step. Your steps should look like

[image]

VSO/VSTS build has a task available with `Archive files` to achieve the same.

Alternatively, if the standard Archive files step doesn't work for you, you can use a powershell step. The powershell command will look like the following.

```
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $Destination)
```

- Source should be all the files/folders from gulp output you wish to deploy
- Destination here should correspond to input for the webdeploy/ WebApp deployment step.

Comment: In Azure Deployment task, I have given the archive file path($(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip) as Web Deploy package path but its not working. It throwing error as Downloading artifacts failed: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ArtifactRepository.Definition.ArtifactDownloadException: No artifacts are available in the build

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this extension to create a ZIP file. I used it for a situation similar to yours:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trackyon.trackyonadvantage

Answer (score 1):

"Azure Web App Deployment" task requires a web deploy zip package. You can either add one more task to create a zip package for the build output as other two answers indicated or add some code in your "gulpfile.js" to generate a zip package during the gulp build and then publish the zip package to artifact.

If you don't want to create a zip package for the build output, then you can use [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task) task to deploy the build to Azure Web App via [FTP Deploy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#ftp).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a zip file with PowerShell, assuming you're running on a Windows agent.

`Command Line` task

Command: `powershell`
Arguments: `-Command "&{Add-Type -assembly 'system.io.compression.filesystem'; [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory('$(Build.StagingDirectory)\Zip', '$(Build.StagingDirectory)\$(BuildConfiguration)Deploy.zip')}"`

Obviously, replace `$(Build.StagingDirectory)\Zip` with whatever folder you want zipped up and `$(Build.StagingDirectory)\$(BuildConfiguration)Deploy.zip` with whatever you want the file named.